# Illustrator export creates white borders at the edges

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, export

Just working on a logo, but when I export the logo to svg (for a website) I get white borders at the edges and the shadow (see picture). Anyone knows how this can happen and what I can do to prevent this? In Illustrator the logo is perfect but exporting to svg/png/jpeg etc brings up this problem

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to make sure the elements and artboard are aligned to the pixel grid.

It's bad if your toolbar looks like this:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/93mZt.png]

Round those numbers and try exporting again to see if that helps.

You can also set it up so your objects align to the grid automatically in the future by checking the Align to Pixel Grid box in the Transform window.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RjmL.png]

Answer (score 1):

Don't have enough reputation to comment, so leaving this as a second answer.

HandsomePhil's answer is correct, but when working with a raster element in Illustrator CC 2019 on Windows, there was no "Align to Pixel Grid" checkbox. Instead, I had to right click the raster element and click "Make Pixel Perfect" and the white border around the raster element went away.

Comment: My export looks much better, thank you!